# overloaded function with no contextual type information | cannot resolve overloaded function 'swap' based on conversion to type 'int'

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am trying to write my own bubble sort algorithm as an exercise. I do not understand the two error messages. Can anyone point out the problem with my code?

```
// Bubble sort algorithm
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int array[], int arraySize); // bubbleSort prototype

int main(void)
{
        const int arraySize = 10;
        int array[arraySize] = {2,3,6,5,7,8,9,3,7,4};

        cout << "Unsorted: ";
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
                cout << setw(5) << array[i];

        cout << "Sorted: " << bubbleSort(array, arraySize);
}

void bubbleSort(int array[], int arraySize)
{
        const int max = arraySize;
        int swap = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        {
                if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
                {
                        swap = array[i + 1];
                        array[i + 1] = array[i];
                        array[i] = swap;
                }
                else
                        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where are the error messages ?

Comment: Sorry:
overloaded function with no contextual type information
cannot resolve overloaded function 'swap' based on conversion to type 'int'

Comment: He was asking for the line number the compiler gave in the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see that you are using

```
using namespace std;
```

So when you type

```
array[i] = swap;
```

The compiler cannot disambiguate whether you are referring to the `std::swap` function or your `int swap` variable. In fact it looks like it assumed you were referring to the function and tried to somehow convert it to type `int`. Try renaming your variable to something else.

In general, try to stay away from `using` directives, to avoid name collisions like this.

Answer (score 3):

```
array[i] = swap;
```

This line is causing problem. It is better to change the name of `swap` local variable, as there exists already a function with same name, in `std` namespace which is brought into scope by the line `using namespace std;` which is to be avoided, anyway.

I would also suggest you to declare the variable, inside the if-block where it is *actually* used:

```
if(array[i] > array[i + 1])
{
     //declare temp here where it is actually used!
     int temp = array[i + 1]; 
     array[i + 1] = array[i];
     array[i] = temp;
}
```

Best practice: reduce the scope local variables by delaying their declarations, which means declare them where they are actually used. Do not declare them in the beginning of the function.

Another way to fix the problem in your code is to give the compiler *a context* which you can by doing this (*though I wouldn't suggest this solution; it is just for you to know*):

```
array[i] = (int)swap; //giving compiler contextual type information
```

When you cast `swap` to `int`, the compiler can know that `swap` refers to the local variable, not the function which is defined in `std` namespace.

Comment: Oh ... I din't know about "contextual type information", which can be given explicitly like this.

Comment: @iammilind: Its very common when you've overloaded functions, then you mention the *type* of the function, either in explicit cast, or as target type. Say, there are many overloaded functions with name `f` in your project, then `auto x = f` will give compilation error saying ambiguous function name. To resolve it, either you write `ftype x = f`, or `auto x = (ftype)f`, where `ftype` is the type of the function you intended to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "Sorted: " << bubbleSort(array, arraySize);
```

The return type of the function is `void`. There is nothing to print for. If you need to print the sorted array, you need to iterate over the array elements after the function call.